# Make a text box automatically fill depending on drop-down selection (laravel)

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I'm new in laravel, i just want to ask if how can i fill another textbox when i select a data in a dropdown.
In my table named 'booklist'
i have this columns 'book_title' and 'type_id'
which has a relationship with 'booktypes' table
with columns, 'type_id' and 'book_types'

i want to show the book types based on what book title i select in my dropdown
(e.g Geometry (title) Math (type))

now i can only show and select all the book types in my dropdown based on this codes

```
<div class="form-group">
<label>Select Book</label>
<select class="form-control" name="book_id">
<option value="">-----------</option>
 @foreach ($booklist as $boo)
<option value="{{$boo->book_id}}">{{ $boo->book_title }}</option>
 @endforeach
</select>
</div>
```

my ShelfController

```
public function addshelfa()
{
    return view('addshelf.addtoshelfa',['booklist'=>Booklist::all()]);
}
```

if a select for example Geometry want to show its type in here:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label>Book Type</label>


<input value="" type="text" class="form-control" name="type_id" disabled>



</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

For achieve this kind of functionality you need to add ajax call, this is going to be a long answer. So, i make it step by step and this is a rough phototype.

step 1: Your ajax functionality part,

```
  // meta tag add inside your html head
  <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />

    // ajax header setup
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });

    /**
     * change book action
     */
    // you need to give id attribute to book_id field.
    $(document).on('change', '#book_id', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var book_id = $('#book_id').val();
        var route = "/book-type/set";
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: route,
            data: {
                book_id: book_id
            },
            success: function (data) {
                   // you can check for status here 
                   $("input[name=type_id]").val(data.book_type_id);

            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest) {
                // toastr.error('Something Went Wrong !');
            }
        });
    });
```

step 2: backend handle part

Define route for handle request,

```
    Route::post('/book-type/set', 'YourController@bookTypeSet');
```

Define Your method,

```
    public function bookTypeSet(Request $request) 
    {
        // this is a rough prototype you need to give your actual data from here
        $bookId = $request->get('book_id');

        $book = Book::findOrFail($bookId);

        $bookType = $book->bookTypes;

        return response()->json(['book_type_id'=>$bookType->id, 'status'=>'200']);
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the help i will try to understand first the code before trying to use it, i appreciated the help.

Comment: excuse me sir can you please explain to me the codes briefly im trying to use the code but i cant show the desired output ....

Comment: Can you tell me where you don't understand extactly ? Or what portion of answer you don't understand because it's hard to tell you all things in word.